Vite build stuck on 'modules transform'
While building a svelte application with vite, the build process gets stuck on 'modules transform'. No error is reported on the building logs.
I've tried several things, including but not limited to:

removing and reinstalling node modules
removing unused libs from package.json
disabling the minification process.
using a plugin to let vite accept top level awaits
building using a different js runtime (bun)
building in another machine

npm run dev works perfectly fine, so i don't think it is a problem related to the application itself.

Edit:
Seems like manually updating every svelte related library and vite did the trick

what does "gets stuck on"  mean? Does the process never stop?

It hangs there, doing nothing, after the 'modules transform' operation

You should publish a reproducible project.
